# Converting OSM or PBF file to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, convert, pbf

I'm trying to get some OpenStreetMap data into the ESRI ecosystem. I've been using geofabrik.de to download the data. I tried using QGIS to convert, but it must have a field or size limit, because it always ends up deleting the fields that I need. I also tried using ogr2ogr, but the documentation is so bad I can't figure it out.

Comment: geofabrik.de has shapefiles...  example http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html  > http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england-latest-free.shp.zip

Comment: Did you already check the OSM documentation? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles

Comment: QGIS uses Ogr2Ogr in the background. QGIS is not "dropping" field, it's the default OSMCONF.ini file provided by ogr2ogr to remove some fields. THe file must be edited https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html Side note, have a look to QuickOSM plugin, maybe it's way to explore.

Comment: Shapefile has a 2 GB file size limit and OSM country files are usually bigger. ESRI can read GeoPackages and QGIS can also write file geodatabases.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works